# How to use ALERTIFY JS (v1.9.0) in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, alertifyjs

I am trying to get AlertifyJS (v1.9.0) to work in  my angular 2 app.
I have the following in vendor.ts

```
import "alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js";
import "alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css";
```

with the following call to alertify

```
openConfirmationDialog(message: string, okCallback: () => any) {

    alertify.confirm(message, function (e: any) {
        if (e) {
            okCallback();
        } else {
        }
    });
}
```

but keep getting the error

```
: Cannot find name 'alertify'.
```

Answer (score 4):

OK folks, I got it working. it was as simple as just putting this line

```
var alertify = require('alertifyjs');
```

just immediately after my imports statements

Answer (score 3):

Install package:

```
npm install alertify.js@^1.0.12 --save
```

and then you can use in your component by importing it in file,

```
import * as alertify from 'alertify.js';//import

alertify.logPosition('bottom right').log("Pattern Selected");//example
```

*I specified version because i tested it with and its working fine for me. previous version was not working.*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

By mistake I added css and js paths to "style" but for "test"

There are two "style" sections in the angular.json file :)

Ps Angullar 11 we don't need add services to app.module (providers array).

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css",
          "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.less"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> alertify.js plugin file include index.html

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var alertify:any;

alertify message inside function.
alertify.success(response.msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import alertifyjs from 'alertifyjs';
```

> For this you have to install `alertifyjs` package

So use the below command

```
npm i alertifyjs
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install it with
`npm install alertifyjs --save`

Next you have to import the following in the angular.json file

> "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js" in the scripts array and
>
> "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css" and
>
> "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/default.min.css" in the styles array

You also need to import the alertifyjs in the component you have to use it.
Write `import * as alertify from 'alertifyjs';` at the top of the component to import it in your component.
for eg:
`alertify.minimalDialog || alertify.dialog('minimalDialog',function(){ return { main:function(content){ this.setContent(content); } }; }); alertify.minimalDialog("Minimal button-less dialog.");`

Answer (score 0):

It's through a two-step approach:

```
// import 
import alertifyjs from 'alertifyjs';

// set for global if you wish to use outside of this file (such as Laravel app.js)
window.alertify = alertifyjs;
```

If you only want to use in that file, just import and use as `alertify.success()` without setting as global variable.

Answer (score 0):

**For angular 11**

```
npm install alertifyjs --save
```

and then on *`angular.json`* under `styles` array put these lines

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css",
    "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

And then under on `angular.json` file under `scripts` array put this line.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"
]
```

After that create new service called `alertify.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare let alertify: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertifyService {

  constructor() { }
  
  confirm(message: string, okCallback: () => any) {
    alertify.confirm(message, function(e:any) {
      if (e) {
        okCallback();
      }
    });
  }

  success(message: string) {
    alertify.success(message);
  }

  error(message: string) {
    alertify.error(message);
  }

  warning(message: string) {
    alertify.success(message)
  }

  message(message: string) {
    alertify.message(message)
  }
}
```

Now register this service in `app.module.ts` at `provider` array

```
  providers: [
    AlertifyService
  ]
```

Now inject this service in your componenet.

Answer (score 0):

First step install the alertify library

```
npm install alertifyjs --save
```

> Import the alertify in your service

```
import alertifyjs from 'alertifyjs';
```

> User this example code

```
  success(message: string) {
    alertify.success(message);
  }
```